# Bash script to setup new Debian installs

Tags: bash, linux, shell, installer

This script is run directly after a fresh install of Debian, to do:

- sets up syntax highlighting in `nano`,
- sets up `iptables`,
- sets up ssh,
- sets up custom `bashrc` files and `ls` colors,
- creates users on the system if needed,
- checks if user has a password set and sets it if not,
- installs `non-free firmware` and sets up `apt` with `virtualbox` deb file and `multimedia` deb.

There was mention of `debconf` but I've never heard about that.

Would you use `sudo` as I did to access other users on the system?

Could you add some features to the program that are good practice for setting up new installs?

Can you see a way for me to use `getops` to strengthen the program?

Is there anything in the program that I don't need?

```
#!/bin/bash -x

SCRIPTNAME=`basename "$0"`

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "No arguments supplied"
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME user1name user2name\(optional\) user3name\(optional\)"
    sleep 10
    exit 27
fi

sleep 5
echo "Setting up server.........."
sleep 10

DIRBASHRCROOT="$HOME"/.bashrcroot
DIRBASHRC="$HOME"/.bashrc
#CURRENTDIR="./"
BASHRC=.bashrc
NANORC=.nanorc
BASHRCROOT=.bashrcroot
ROOT=root
USER1="$1"
USER2="$2"
USER3="$3"
USER_PROGRAMMER=""
SOURCE=sources.list

echo "Please select/provide the port-number for ssh in iptables and sshd_config:"
read port
PORT=$port
################# Make my variable global for all ########################3↓
echo "export CURRENTDIR=\"/tmp/svaka\"" >> /root/.bashrc
touch /etc/profile.d/bashProgrammer.sh
echo "export CURRENTDIR=\"/tmp/svaka\"" >> /etc/profile.d/bashProgrammer.sh
. /root/.bashrc
. /etc/profile
. /etc/profile.d/bashProgrammer.sh
################ Users and access settings #####################
############################### make all files writable, executable and        readable in the working directory#########
chmod 777 $CURRENTDIR/*
if [ ! "$?" = 0 ]
then
      echo "Couldnt give write, read and execute permission to config files in   svaka, exiting now........"
exit 127
fi
#########################################################
checkIfUser()
{
    for name in "$@"
    do
        if id -u "$name" #>/dev/null 2>&1
        then
            echo "User: $name exists....setting up now\!"
            sleep 5
        else
            echo "User: "$name" does not exists....creating now\!"
            useradd -m -s /bin/bash "$name" #>/dev/null 2>&1
            sleep 5
        fi
    done
}
checkIfUser $1 $2 $3
################33 user passwords
userPass()
{
    for i in "$@"
    do
        if [ "$i" = root ]
        then
            continue
        fi
        if [[ $(passwd --status "$i" | awk '{print $2}') = NP ]]
        then
            echo "$i doesn't have a password."
            echo "Changing password for $i:"
            echo $i:$i"YOURSTRONGPASSWORDHERE12345Áá" | chpasswd
            if [ "$?" = 0 ]
                then
                echo "Password for user $i changed successfully"
                sleep 5
            fi
        fi
    done
}
userPass $1 $2 $3
################################################ setting up iptables ####################3

cat << EOT >> /etc/iptables.test.rules
*filter

IPTABLES CODE HERE

COMMIT
EOT
sleep 5
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.test.rules
sleep 5
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.up.rules
sleep 3
printf "#!/bin/bash\n/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules" > /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables
chmod +x /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables
sleep 6
###################################################33 sshd_config
cp -f "$CURRENTDIR/sshd_config" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i "s/Port 34504/Port $PORT/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
chmod 644 /etc/ssh/sshd_config
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
#################################################3333 Remove or comment out DVD/cd line from sources.list

sed -i '/deb cdrom:\[Debian GNU\/Linux/s/^/#/' /etc/apt/sources.list
####################################################33 update system
apt update && apt upgrade -y
##########################################3 Disable login www #########
passwd -l www-data
###############################################################
############################# check if programs installed and/or install
if [ ! -x /usr/bin/git ] || [ ! -x /usr/bin/wget ] || [ ! -x /usr/bin/curl ] || [ ! -x /usr/bin/gcc ] || [ ! -x /usr/bin/make ]
then
    echo "Some tools with which to work with data not found installing now......................"
    apt install -y git wget curl gcc make
fi

#####################################################3 update sources.list
cp -f $CURRENTDIR/$SOURCE /etc/apt/sources.list
chmod 644 /etc/apt/sources.list
wget http://www.deb-multimedia.org/pool/main/d/deb-multimedia-keyring/deb-multimedia-keyring_2016.8.1_all.deb
dpkg -i deb-multimedia-keyring_2016.8.1_all.deb
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
apt update && apt upgrade -y
apt install -y vlc vlc-data browser-plugin-vlc mplayer youtube-dl libdvdcss2 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 smplayer mencoder
sleep 5
apt update && apt upgrade -y
sleep 5
#################################### firmware
apt install -y firmware-linux-nonfree firmware-linux
sleep 5
################ NANO SYNTAX-HIGHLIGHTING #####################3
if [ ! -d "$CURRENTDIR/nanorc"  ]
then
    if [ "$UID" != 0 ]
    then
        sudo -u "$ROOT" bash <<'EOF'
        sleep 5
        git clone https://github.com/nanorc/nanorc.git
        sleep 5
        cd nanorc
        make install-global
        sleep 5
        cp -f "$CURRENTDIR/.nanorc" /etc/nanorc
        chown root:root /etc/nanorc
        chmod 644 /etc/nanorc
        if [ "$?" = 0 ]
        then
            echo "Implementing a custom nanorc file succeeded\!"
        else
            echo "Nano setup DID NOT SUCCEED\!"
        fi
EOF
    else
        echo "Doing user: $USER....please, wait\!"
        git clone https://github.com/nanorc/nanorc.git
        sleep 5
        cd nanorc
        sleep 5
        make install-global
        sleep 5
        cp -f "$CURRENTDIR/$NANORC" /etc/nanorc
        chown root:root /etc/nanorc
        chmod 644 /etc/nanorc
        if [ "$?" = 0 ]
        then
            echo "Implementing a custom nanorc file succeeded\!"
        else
            echo "Nano setup DID NOT SUCCEED\!"
        fi
    fi
fi

echo "Finished setting up nano\!"
################ LS_COLORS SETTINGS #############################

if [ "$UID" != 0 ]
then
    echo "This program should be run as root, exiting\! now....."
    exit 1
   # sudo -i -u "$ROOT" bash <<'EOF'
   # BASHRCROOT=.bashrcroot
   # cp "$CURRENTDIR/$BASHRCROOT" "$HOME"/.bashrc
   # wget https://raw.github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS/master/LS_COLORS -O "$HOME"/.dircolors
   # echo 'eval $(dircolors -b $HOME/.dircolors)' >> "$HOME"/.bashrc
   # . "$HOME"/.bashrc
#EOF
else
    cp -f "$CURRENTDIR/$BASHRCROOT" "$HOME"/.bashrc
    chown root:root "$HOME"/.bashrc
    chmod 644 "$HOME"/.bashrc
    sleep 5
    wget https://raw.github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS/master/LS_COLORS -O "$HOME"/.dircolors
    sleep 5
    echo 'eval $(dircolors -b $HOME/.dircolors)' >> "$HOME"/.bashrc
    sleep 5
    . "$HOME"/.bashrc
fi
for user in "$@"
do
    if [ "$user" = root ]
    then
        continue
    fi
    sudo -i -u "$user" user="$user" bash <<'EOF'
    sleep 5
    cp -f $CURRENTDIR/.bashrc "$HOME"/.bashrc
    chown $user:$user "$HOME"/.bashrc
    sleep 5
    chmod 644 "$HOME"/.bashrc
    sleep 5
    wget https://raw.github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS/master/LS_COLORS -O "$HOME"/.dircolors
    sleep 5
    echo 'eval $(dircolors -b $HOME/.dircolors)' >> "$HOME"/.bashrc
    . "$HOME"/.bashrc
EOF
done

echo "Finished setting up your system\!"
echo rm -rf /tmp/svaka
```

Here's a question about this code on unix/linux [stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466312/getting-access-to-a-variable-inside-a-sudo-clause-in-a-script-with-eof/466317#466317)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Welcome to Code Review!

It is a good practice if you start verifying your shell scripts [against shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck). Currently, it lists quite a few issues:

```
Line 3:
SCRIPTNAME=`basename "$0"`
           ^-- SC2006: Use $(...) notation instead of legacy backticked `...`.

Line 17:
DIRBASHRCROOT="$HOME"/.bashrcroot
^-- SC2034: DIRBASHRCROOT appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).

Line 18:
DIRBASHRC="$HOME"/.bashrc
^-- SC2034: DIRBASHRC appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).

Line 20:
BASHRC=.bashrc
^-- SC2034: BASHRC appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).

Line 24:
USER1="$1"
^-- SC2034: USER1 appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).

Line 25:
USER2="$2"
^-- SC2034: USER2 appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).

Line 26:
USER3="$3"
^-- SC2034: USER3 appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).

Line 27:
USER_PROGRAMMER=""
^-- SC2034: USER_PROGRAMMER appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).

Line 31:
read port
^-- SC2162: read without -r will mangle backslashes.

Line 37:
. /root/.bashrc
  ^-- SC1091: Not following: /root/.bashrc was not specified as input (see shellcheck -x).

Line 38:
. /etc/profile
  ^-- SC1091: Not following: /etc/profile was not specified as input (see shellcheck -x).

Line 39:
. /etc/profile.d/bashProgrammer.sh
  ^-- SC1091: Not following: /etc/profile.d/bashProgrammer.sh was not specified as input (see shellcheck -x).

Line 42:
chmod 777 $CURRENTDIR/*
          ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 43:
if [ ! "$?" = 0 ]
       ^-- SC2181: Check exit code directly with e.g. 'if mycmd;', not indirectly with $?.

Line 58:
            echo "User: "$name" does not exists....creating now\!"
                         ^-- SC2027: The surrounding quotes actually unquote this. Remove or escape them.
                         ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 64:
checkIfUser $1 $2 $3
            ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
               ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
                  ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 78:
            echo $i:$i"YOURSTRONGPASSWORDHERE12345Áá" | chpasswd
                 ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
                    ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 79:
            if [ "$?" = 0 ]
                 ^-- SC2181: Check exit code directly with e.g. 'if mycmd;', not indirectly with $?.

Line 87:
userPass $1 $2 $3
         ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
            ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
               ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 126:
cp -f $CURRENTDIR/$SOURCE /etc/apt/sources.list
      ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 165:
        cd nanorc
        ^-- SC2164: Use 'cd ... || exit' or 'cd ... || return' in case cd fails.

Line 172:
        if [ "$?" = 0 ]
             ^-- SC2181: Check exit code directly with e.g. 'if mycmd;', not indirectly with $?.

Line 202:
    echo 'eval $(dircolors -b $HOME/.dircolors)' >> "$HOME"/.bashrc
         ^-- SC2016: Expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that.

Line 204:
    . "$HOME"/.bashrc
      ^-- SC1090: Can't follow non-constant source. Use a directive to specify location.
```

---

In addition to shellcheck advices; I'd also point that you currently have a very long script executing statements one after the other. Split them into multiple small functions and call them as you deem fit.

---

Why do you wait 10 seconds when the number of required arguments was not available? Since it is a non-zero exit, user will anyway get sufficiently notified. Same goes for the `sleep 5` and `10` just after the parameter count check.

---

You redirect `echo "export CURRENTDIR=\"/tmp/svaka\""` twice to 2 different files. Make use of [`tee`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) and pipe the echo a single time.

---

You have a lot of stub code in the script. Clean it up; remove unused statements/declarations/tasks and post another question with the updated code.